# Module Editor in OCaml

Tags: ocaml

First, define the structure part of the module `Editor`. Specify an abstract data type
`Editor.t` of the edited text. Represent the edited text as a list of lines. Further, represent
a line by a list of words of type `string`.

Implement a function `delete : Editor.t -> string -> Editor.t` that deletes all
instances of a word from the complete text.

Define the signature of the module `Editor` to hide the abstract data type and to include
the signatures of public functions.

Finally, define also an instance of module `Editor` by
specifying the previously defined structure and signature.

Need to construct Module using this definition. I am not sure how to define structure and signature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An abstract data type is one whose internal structure cannot be seen except by a carefully defined interface. In OCaml this typically means using a module containing a type and specifying a signature that hides the implementation details of that type.

Consider a sample module `A` which contains a type `t` with a constructor `T` which takes an `int`.

```
module A = struct
  type t = T of int
end
```

I can now create an `A.t` value very simply: `let a = A.T 42`.

But maybe I don't want to let an `A.t` value contain a negative int. Well, then it's a shame I can write: `let a = A.T ~-3`. Nothing stops me from doing this.

Unless I make `A.t` an abstract type. First I'd need to specify a signature that does not specify a type for type `t`.

```
module type A_SIG = sig
  type t
end
```

And then constrain `A` to that type.

```
module A : A_SIG = struct
  type t = T of int
end
```

If we evaluate this in the toplevel, we can see the result:

```
# module type A_SIG = sig
    type t
  end

  module A : A_SIG = struct
    type t = T of int
  end;;
module type A_SIG = sig type t end
module A : A_SIG
```

Now there's a problem. We don't know anything about `A` except that it has a type `t`, so we can't actually build an `A.t` value at all much less do anything with it.

We need to introduce a `make` (call it whatever you want, but `make` is reasonably idiomatic) function and *expose* it in the signature. We should probably also have a `to_int` function to let us get the int value *out* of an `A.t` value.

```
module type A_SIG = sig
  type t
  val make : int -> t
  val to_int : t -> int
end

module A : A_SIG = struct
  type t = T of int

  let make i = 
    if i < 0 then invalid_arg "Must not be negative.";
    T i

  let to_int (T i) = i
end
```

Putting this to the test:

```
# A.make 4;;
- : A.t = <abstr>
# A.make ~-4;;
Exception: Invalid_argument "Must not be negative.".
# A.(make 42 |> to_int);;
- : int = 42
```

This same syntax and approach can be used to solve your editor problem. You need an abstract type and an interface with functions that let you:

1. Construct an `Editor.t` value from a block of text.
2. Access that block of text and remove a string from it, building a new `Editor.t` value with that resulting string.
3. Extract the text from an `Editor.t` value.